# Networking using the host network, for docker not working

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, networking

I am trying to run the demonstration for docker, and host networking using:

```bash
docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx
```

When inspecting the running container using Docker Desktop, it show port 80 as not bound. Also, when navigating to http://localhost:80, I am not able to see the default nginx welcome. I am only able to see any application when I manually bind ports to the host machine; i.e `-p 80:80`. I did give myself a custom local IP address and DNS options (Windows 10). Do I need to modify my hosts file on my system?

[image]

Comment: Host networking doesn't work on MacOS or Windows systems.  Even on native Linux it should be extremely unusual to need it.  What are you actually trying to accomplish by disabling Docker's networking layer?

Comment: @DavidMaze, for learning purposes. I have an alright understanding of Docker and wanted to move toward Kubernetes so just trying to familiarize myself with some of the basics I skipped over.

Comment: There are a bunch of optional pieces of Docker that you almost never need, and I'd put host networking in this bucket.  Use `docker run -p` where it's appropriate and ignore the non-portable host-networking capability.